# How can I disable the display of the Notification Center when pulling down on the screen?

Tags: ios, notifications

I have a little problem with new iPhone notification center. I have a fullscreen game with my custom top menu, which works very similar to the new notification center. Unfortunately, every finger slide from the top of the screen downward shows the handle for pulling the notification center. This hides my handle for my own menu, and it looks a little ugly.

Is there a way to disable the top-down finger slide gesture for displaying the notification center in my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope.

Just like 4-5 multi-gesture at iPad will switch between apps while slicing fluites or playing the piano.