# How to disable the "drag down to view Notifications" feature?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ios5 new Notification Center issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765103/ios5-new-notification-center-issue)

Many apps have established a paradigm like this:
"Drag the top portion of the screen down to reveal something"

Many other apps do something like that already. One of the most famous examples might be Calcbot from Tapbots.

Now with iOS 5 when the user drags down on the top of the screen, there is a good chance the Notifications window will slide in.

Is there a way of saying "for this app, do not slide in Notifications when the user drags down on the top of the screen"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You cannot do this. The only way to stop the Notification Center from immediately appearing is to hide your app's status bar, and even then the 'tab' of the NC will stay appear.

Like Multitasking Gestures in iOS5, you cannot stop this behaviour and must instead rethink how your apps work to suit Apple's changes.