# Custom drag view from top edge of screen conflict with Notification Center

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

I would like to have a custom view being pulled from the top of the screen with an `UIScreenEdgePangesture` but I can't find a way to avoid having the Notification Center view being pulled instead.

Comment: That's the way notification center works

Comment: I know i just want to not have the notification center being pulled but my own custom view

Comment: I think its not allowed or cannot do this please check [this][1] answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783924/how-to-disable-the-drag-down-to-view-notifications-feature

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you're out of luck here. Thats the way apple built it. You can't disable the notification center