# Is it possible to deactivate: when user touches status bar and drag down, iPhone Info Panel appears

Tags: ios, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable the display of the Notification Center when pulling down on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765103/how-can-i-disable-the-display-of-the-notification-center-when-pulling-down-on-th)

May be the question is incorrect and really I think this is impossible to implement, but never the less, I'm interested in finding the answer.
I wanna deactivate usual iPhone behavior: when user touches status bar and drag down, iPhone Info Panel appears.

So, when user does that, nothing should happen.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This happens even if the status bar is hidden (e.g., game apps) when you tap and drag very near the top of the screen. I'm not sure, but I don't think Apple would let you override this, since it's a system wide function...

Answer (score 0):

You can't "deactivate usual iPhone behavior". You can't change anything on the device. The only thing your app is in control of is your app. Your app can't affect anything else on the device. If you want to change any settings on the device, you can't. The user of the device has to do that. They own the device, it is up to them. Not your app.

Unless it's jailbroken, but that's another story.